# How we can check image dimention an according to criteria upload image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

here I want coding for checking the criteria. I have code for adjust image according to given area. suppose i have 300X400px image .but i want that image in 200X300px area.
but not by adjust the size but with crop the image.(By ImgSelectArea)

my coding is:

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

$("#file").change(function(e) {
    var file, img;


    if ((file = this.files[0])) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
        };
        img.onerror = function() {
            alert( "not a valid file: " + file.type);
        };
        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);


    }

});
```

html:

```
<p>image is set to 100x100 pixels!</p>

<img id="draggable" src="http://jotform.org/demo/jquery-image-area-select-plugin/images/sweet-dogs.jpg" />

<div id="dim"></div>
```

Hope you understand my question

Comment: What does `#file` refer to? There are no objects here with and id of file.

Comment: Why don't you use the 'live preview' example on the main website [Here](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/)? You could change the aspect ratio to 2:3.